# Make installer in .NET visual studio 2008 but getting projects compiled

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction, installation

I have several solutions `(c# code which connects to sqlserver as stored procedures)` in their corresponding folder, and I'd like to make a setup for this, but as I want to get optimal with results, I want that the solutions to be compiled again in the machine of the user when user is installing the software and then check the connection to a sql so user can execute generated stored procs.

(I mean to generate a single folder with all the solutions compiled and then deploy them so user can use them in a stored procedure in SQL)server

As a precondition I ask user to have already the cs compiler and sql server installed.

What could I do, [I was following a tutorial](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/0effb67d-1d63-45b1-b3ff-068eb0a7a62e) but I do not know how to compile and prepare all the database conection with sql, also how to deploy all cs code... is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio setup projects don't really support this, so you're better off with a different setup authoring tool. Here is a list which can get you started: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

You need the following features in a setup tool:

- SQL scripts support
- SQL connection testing support
- launch conditions and prerequisite support

An installer simply copies resources in the appropriate locations and performs some actions to configure those resources. So you first need to determine how you can install your application manually (manual copy/paste and configuration), and only then try to replicate that logic in an installer.